# Dart tests: excpect stream to emit nothing

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, bloc

I want to check that some `Stream` (e.g. bloc) emits nothing during unit test.

**More detailed description:** I use [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) packages. System under test is a bloc. My test:

```
  test('sut emits nothing', () {
    final event = SomeEvent(false);
    sut.add(event);
    expectLater(
      sut,
      emitsNothing,    // <---- HERE I want to check that sut emits nothing
    );
  });
```

Here is mapping function of my bloc:

```
  @override
  Stream<State> mapEventToState(Event event) async* {
    if (event is SomeEvent) {
      // If `flag` is true - then bloc emits a state,
      // if `flag` is false - then bloc emits nothing.
      if (event.flag) {    
        yield State.someState;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is code of `SomeEvent`:

```
abstract class Event extends Equatable {}

class SomeEvent extends Event {
  final bool flag;

  SomeEvent(this.flag);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [flag];
}
```

Can I check it out? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this by using [bloc_test](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_test) package.

```
blocTest(
  'CounterBloc emits no events',
  build: () => CounterBloc(),
  act: (_) {}, // no action taken
  expect: [], // no event emitted
);
```

Comment: I tried bloc_test packege as you adviced. It is realy useful and it allows to check if bloc emits nothing! Not with `verify` option, but simply with passing [] to `expect` parameter. Thank you so much! I already voted up you answer. If you want me to accept it as right, please add some info about passing [] to `expect` and some related code.

Comment: @Mol0ko Thats interesting, I will give it a try in my spare time meanwhile I have updated the code to your liking. let me know if I should add anything specific :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [flutter_test](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html) library, you can use `neverEmits(anything)`:

```
test('sut emits nothing', () async {
  final event = SomeEvent(false);
  sut.add(event);

  unawaitet(expectLater(sut, neverEmits(anything)));
  await sut.close();
);
```

});

It is imported to close the stream at the end of the test, otherwise the test will time out in the good case.

It does not seem to be sufficient if the stream is closed in `tearDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this issue is still relevant.

Actually, there's no need to write streams & yield statements from scratch, as per the newer versions of bloc. But as we are setting the Later calles in testing, we will need to parse a bloc-stream while expecting the result. So, the solution to your code is to use bloc.stream instead of bloc.state which converts the bloc to a bloc stream & yeilds the output in order. Do remember that the stream does not contain the initial/EmptyState(), but all other events are handle in order & hence emitted the same.
Refer to the below code snippet for the proper implementat,

```
This is the bloc file that contains the bloc logic as per the latest versions.

///<inputs an event, outputs the state> => <NumberTriviaEvent, 
NumberTriviaState>
class NumberTriviaBloc extends Bloc<NumberTriviaEvent, NumberTriviaState> {
  final GetConcreteNumberTrivia concreteNumberTrivia;
  final GetRandomNumberTrivia randomNumberTrivia;
  final InputConverter inputConverter;

  NumberTriviaBloc(
      {required this.concreteNumberTrivia,
      required this.randomNumberTrivia,
      required this.inputConverter}) : super(EmptyState()) {
    on<NumberTriviaEvent>((event, emit) async{
        if(event is GetTriviaForConcreteNumber){
          final input = inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger(event.numberString);
          input.fold((lFailure){
             emit( const ErrorState(errorMessage: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE));
          }, (rSuccess) {
             emit(const LoadedState(numberTrivia: NumberTrivia(text: 'sample test', number: 1)));
          });
        }
    });
  }
}

This is the test file that tests the output over the block that is written above.

    test('should emit [Error] when theres an invalid input', () {
      //  arrange
      when(inputConverter.stringToUnsignedInteger('abc'))
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Left(InvalidInputFailure()));

      //  assert Later
      /// As we will be checking if the emit contains the expected result, we will use expectLater() method in test
      /// which puts the particular test on hold until the data is been emitted(upper limit 30 seconds) & then applies the checks
      expectLater(
        bloc.stream,
        emitsInOrder([
          const ErrorState(errorMessage: INVALID_INPUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
          ]));

      //  act
      bloc.add(const GetTriviaForConcreteNumber(numberString: 'abc'));
    });
  });

Learning Source: Reso Coders
```